# How to avoid long waits while waiting for asserted throw?

Tags: junit5, swtbot

I'm testing a menu item for non-existence (which is relevant as I want to check whether a condition is correctly met which hides the item). Therefore, I call `SWTBotRootMenu#contextMenu(String text) throws WidgetNotFoundException` in `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows`.

However, having a number of these tests makes running the tests really slow, as the `WidgetNotFoundException` is thrown only after a 5s timeout it seems.

Is there a way to set the timeout to a shorter value? Or avoid the wait altogether in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check menu for missing item you can get content `SWTBotRootMenu#contextMenu()` of whole menu and perform basic check if tested item is present or not.

```
SWTBotRootMenu context = menu.contextMenu();
assertFalse(context.menuItems().contains(text));
```